# How to disable innodb_doublewrite for MySQL at Amazon RDS?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Please can anyone help me to disable "innodb_doublewrite" for my MySQL database hosted at Amazon RDS. I need this as we need to quickly update around 15 Million rows.

I know there is a startup option for this:

```
--skip-innodb_doublewrite
```

But how to use it?

Apart from that, Amazon RDS Parameters Group does not show the option of "innodb_doublewrite" for editing. Amazon does not also allow direct editing of `my.cnf` file.

I can access the MySQL through my Linux Server. But don't know exactly how to use the startup option for Amazon RDS. Please can any one help me to disable this option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AWS support confirmed the following as of August 2, 2015:

"innodb_doublewrite can't be modified in RDS MySQL instances"

Comment: Oh thanks a lot :) I was going round and round finding how to disable it. Maybe they think it;s unsafe to disable "innodb_doublewrite".

Comment: It is technically unsafe as this stops MySQL from performing transactions. If you know you won't need a logical rollback and only would rollback on a failed flush to disk then potentially the filesystem might cover you (depending on what filesystem you are using) but you have no guarantees. It's definitely not something to disable for any lengthy period of time in a production system.

Comment: @sadasivaUlaka, yes they did add "Enabling this parameter can have dire consequences for data durability, ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/glossary.html#glos_doublewrite_buffer". But of course, this is highly dependent on your use case.

Answer (score 1):

RDS is a managed database service that provides some abstractions to managing a database directly on EC2 but in exchange you lose some flexibility including what options you are able to apply to your database instance.

All start up parameters that would normally be specified in my.cnf should instead be applied via the RDS Parameter Groups but, as you mention in your question, `innodb_doublewrite` is not one of the configurable parameters.

If the data you are updating is not likely to be updated during normal operation you could always attempt to make the update on a read slave (`SET GLOBAL READ_ONLY=0` first) and then promote the read replica and point your application at this instance.

Comment: READ_ONLY is already set to OFF. Does this result into faster writes?

Comment: Your read slaves will be set to READ_ONLY by default so only users with SUPER privileges can write to it. My suggestion is to make your 15 million updates to a read only slave that isn't serving any traffic and then promote it when you are done. Updates from the master should continue to be replicated to the instance you are updating so the only disruption will be during the promotion and when you point your application at the new instance.